# What does exactly the CookiePolicyMiddleware do in startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, middleware

Microsoft provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cookiepolicy.cookiepolicymiddleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0) a prompt description how to use this middleware but it has no mention of what the middleware exactly does. What is good for/what does it exactly do?

The code for initialising the middleware in `startup.cs` is:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);
```

Comment: You can use it for global cookie config. For example setting `Secured` to `true` on all cookies or based on some logic

Comment: Also checks for cookie consent if needed.

Comment: @Artur so it checks whether Secure is true on cookies with one of its options?

Comment: @juunas can you elaborate?

Comment: This is a good example https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Comment: You can also check the middleware source code here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e687ea05a6dc8185b0ed0bf95f7a618f80d4a3f0/src/Security/CookiePolicy/src/CookiePolicyMiddleware.cs

Comment: You can refer to the offcical [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookie-policy-middleware) about cookie authentication.